# Как с помощью vk_api оставить комментарий на стене в группе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

У меня возникла проблема мне необходимо с помощью vk_api отправлять комментарии на стену в группе. Как это реализовать?

Comment: https://vk.com/dev.php?method=wall.post

Comment: А vk api позволяет вообще это делать? Если да, то любой враппер берешь и пишешь, тот же https://github.com/python273/vk_api